# In java replace the regex with string

Tags: java, regex

In java I am using regex `\".*?\"`.
I used this for replacing all the string with doublequote with a term String.

```
Ex:
INPUT: Functions.unescapeJson("test")
Result : Functions.unescapeJson("String")
```

But now I wanted to exclude some string if they contains double quote. So, I am using `/` as the escape character. How to achieve this.

```
Ex:
INPUT: Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.unescapeJson("test"), "m2m:cin.con"),"payloads_ul.dataFrameOutput"),"[/"Dimming Value/"]")

RESULT: Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.unescapeJson(String), String),String),String)
```

But the result I am getting if I use the previous regex is:

```
Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.unescapeJson(input.mIntegerm/:sgn.nev.rep), String),String),StringDimming ValueString)
```

How to achieve this using regex if it finds `/` it should neglect without replacing original string.

The code that I am using

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String STRINGVALIDATIONREGEX = "\".*?\"";
    String formula = "Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.getJsonPath(Functions.unescapeJson(input.m2m/:sgn.nev.rep), \"m2m:cin.con\"),\"payloads_ul.dataFrameOutput\"),\"[\"Dimming Value\"]\")";
    System.out.println(formula.replace(STRINGVALIDATIONREGEX, "String"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\"(\/?.)*?\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [^/] to match anything that is not a slash.

For example, [^/]?\".*[^/]?\" would catch quotes not preceded by /

Answer (score 1):

```
"((?:[^"]|(?<=\/)")*)"
```

1. `"` match a `"`
2. `[^"]` match a non-quote character
3. `|` or
4. `(?<=\/)")` a quote character that is preceded by a `/`
5. `*` match sub-expressions 2 - 4 zero or more times.
6. `"` match a `"`

[See Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/meInCu/1/)

If you believe that a string such as `"abc/"` is invalid, then you should use the stricter regex:

```
"((?:[^"\/]|\/")*)"
```

1. `"` match `"`
2. `[^"\/]` match a any character that isn't a quote for `/`
3. `|` or
4. `\/"` match a `/"` combination
5. `*` match sub-expressions 2 - 4 zero or more times.
6. `"` match a `"`

[See Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/meInCu/2/)